# How to delete multiple tables with Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I want to delete my parent table (it has ids to entries in other tables) and all the children tables through Criteria. I am trying it with join but I am a bit lost here. Can anyone help me out?

How do I join the tables based on columns and delete the entry based on parent's id?

My Database structure is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is using Criteria your requirement? Because it can be done very easy with JPARepository delete/remove methods and some configuration in the Entity classes.

Comment: Criteria has become my requirement since I am using Micronaut and cascade delete is not supported.